Polynomials that are never divisible by primes congruent to 3 mod 4
I've recently been playing around with some polynomial equations relating to whether or not they're divisible by a prime congruent to 3 mod 4, and I was wondering what other progress has been made in that area (if any), and where I could find more information about that? I also had a specific question, which was if anyone could prove that $x^2-x+1$ isn't divisible by any prime congruent to 3 mod 4 if and only if x is a perfect square. I've already proven that when x is a perfect square, this is true, but i haven't proven that it isn't true for other numbers and i'm not sure how to go about doing that. This has since been resolved, though I am still curious what other research people have done about polynomials which either always do or don't have a prime factor congruent to 3 mod 4 (or a mod b for some numbers a and b).
I've discovered that there are infinitely many pairs of numbers that differ by 2 neither of which are multiples of primes congruent to 3 mod 4, (which are of the form $(2^{2n+1}+1)^2\pm1$ for all integers $n\ge0$,) though both of those numbers are even, so the formula doesn't really lend itself easily to finding other prime numbers.
Another thing that i've discovered is that $\frac{x^{2^n}-1}{x^2-1}$ will never be divisible by a prime number congruent to 3 mod 4.
(Most of these discoveries have stemmed from the fact that x^2+1 can never be congruent (...) and x^2+4 can also never be congruent (...), though the proof I made for that is rather long for this post. Some results that trivially stem from these are that the sum of two consecutive squares can never be congruent (...) and that the sum of two squares $x^2+(x+2)^2$ also can never be congruent (...).)

Have you tried $x = 2$?  $2^2 - 2 - 1 = 1$ is not divisible by any prime.  On the other hand, $4$ is a square and $4^2 - 4 - 1 = 11 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

In fact, if $x$ is any square, $x \equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod 4$, and $x^2 - x - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. so (if $x > 1$ so $x^2 - x - 1 > 0$) $x^2 - x - 1$ must be divisible by a prime $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

I mistyped and meant to type $x^2-x+1$, my apologies;
fixed the typo

$x^2-x+1\equiv0\pmod p$ has a root if and only if $\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=1,$ which, by quadratic reciprocity is true iff $p\equiv1\pmod 3.$ So $p=7,19$ are counterexamples. For example, $5^2-5+1=21$ is divisible by $7.$ Indeed, there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv7\pmod{12}$ which are counterexamples for $x^2-x+1.$

After checking a few more numbers, I realized that x=13 is a counterexample since 157 is a prime congruent to 1 mod 4.

And $(x^6 - 1)/(x^2-1) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$ is divisible by $7$ if $x \equiv 2, 3, 4$ or $5 \pmod 7$.  Or did you mean $(x^{2^n}-1)/(x^2-1)$ rather than $(x^{2n}-1)/(x^2-1)$?

I meant $x^{2^n}$, sorry; I'm not very used to using mathjax

OK, then it is true that primes dividing $(x^{2^n}-1)/(x^2-1)$ are $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.
